# Microsoft Graph api 403 access denied when reading other users

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an application in with angular and nodejs and I need to be able to read another user's list of events. Right now I am attempting to use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/otherusername@companyurl.com/events" this gives me the 403 "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.". However, if I use "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/myusername@companyurl.com/events" it works(as most would expect). My question is, why is it when I use outlook I can use scheduling assistant to see the events for "otherusername@companyurl.com" without being an admin but in my application I cannot see their events due to credentials?

The library I'm using to connect to microsoft graph api is https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js

The delegated permissions I have set in azure are

- View users' email address
- Sign users in
- Read user contacts
- Have full access to user calendars
- Read user calendars
- Send mail as a user
- Read directory data
- Read all users' basic profiles
- Sign in and read user profile

Application permissions (I understand these require admin)

- Read calendars in all mailboxes

[Graph api permission scopes](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes)

Any help is appreciated, thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fugal - This is by design.  You can use FindMeetingTimes API to schedule meetings with other users.  This can be accomplished with just Calendar.Read permission.  See http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes for more info.

For you to view another user's calendar using /events endpoint, you need a special permission (something like Calendar.Read.Shared) that we are still in the process of adding.  Once we add that, you will be able to use /Events to access any calendar that another user has explicitly shared with you.  But if you want to just schedule meetings, FindMeetingTimes should be sufficient.

Comment: Is the documentation for findmeetingtimes going to be expanded on in the future? I can't find documentation on a few of the types used in the request  body(such as locationConstraint, attendeeBase, timeConstraint and duration). The example lower in the page is a bit ambiguous and I keep getting the error 400 "bad request" "unsupported segment type".

Comment: Sorry about this.  Can you file an issue for this on the doc repo on GitHub https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues and we'll try and get this fixed.

Comment: sorry for taking so long to reply. I feel silly now I accidentally had v1.0 instead of beta in the url. Now https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/findMeetingTimes works. However https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/otheruser@organization.com/findMeetingTimes I still get a 403 "ErrorAccessDenied". I do have the permissions for the Calendars.Read scope enabled.

Comment: Glad to know you are unblocked for original issue!  Calendar.Read only lets you access info as signed in user.  Why do you want to call FindMeetingTimes as some other user?

Comment: Oh I see I would have to fill out the attendees and then it will work. I think this is not the way I need to go. I need to be able to see a room user's calendar and then display it and not compare to the current user. It's for a conference room door display my company wants made. I might have to negotiate with our IT admin and see if they can allow my application to have the application permission "read calendars in all mailboxes". Is this feasible or a blatant misuse of the api?