# As a office 365 admin, Can I subscribe to listen events of other 365 users events?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

As a office 365 admin, Can I subscribe to listen events of other 365 users events on microsoft graph?
I can get events for me https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events OR
"/v1.0/users/Admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com/events" --Works Fine...But when as a Admin tries to get events details for other users. I get error
"message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/ABC@tenant.onmicrosoft.com

Is it possible to fetch event details for other users? if yes then please let me know any setting missing at admin side. if not then what is differnece between api with "/v1.0/users/" and "/v1.0/me/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use **Client Credential flow** to get the app-token for the app. And please ensure that the app you register have the **Calendars.Read** scope to read calendars in all mailboxes like figure below:

[image]

Please refer [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) for more detail.

Code request for app-only token:

```
  public static async Task<string> GetTokenAsync(string resource, string clientId, string secrect)
    {
        string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{yourtenant}";
        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);

        ClientCredential clientCredential = new ClientCredential(clientId, secrect);
        AuthenticationResult authResult=await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientCredential);
        return authResult.AccessToken;
    }

  public static void GetAccessTokenByClientCredential()
    {
        string clientId = "";
        string secrect = "";
        string resrouce = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
        string accessToken= TokenHelper.GetTokenAsync(resrouce, clientId, secrect).Result;
        Console.WriteLine($"Access Token: {accessToken}");

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggested setting changes still I am not able to get event details for other users in organization..  "message": "An error occurred when creating an entity. Exception: Server Error. Status Code: Forbidden, Reason: Forbidden". I tried graph.microsoft.io  API (Global Admin logged user) https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com/events --Works fine and https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/users/another@tenant.onmicrosoft.com/events -- ErrorAccessDenied

Comment: How did you get the access token? You can parse the access token from [here](https://jwt.io/). The app-only token should contain **roles** instead of **scp** claim. If the app-only token contains **roles**, you should able to see the value contain **Calendars.Read**.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Fei, I am able to grant the required permissions to application. But still not able to get rid of access denied error. My application manifest contains -- oauth2Permissions :[ ... "value": "user_impersonation"] I am not sure if this is the issue. Also tried to create "appRoles" manually in manifest but no luck so far. [btw sample downloaded from here https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample]

Comment: Hi Fei, I am not sure, if these permissions are still relevant if things are not implemented from microsoft side..

Comment: @ManojP I recommenced you that parse the token from the link provide above to see whether the permission was set correctly. The sample you provided is for user-delegated token. To read the events of others in your organization, you need to use the **app-only** token. You can follow the link  in the orignal pose to get a app-only token. Then you can use the **Fiddler** to make the request easily.

Comment: @Mrp The scenario you provide is using delegate token. We can use app-token to get the resource from others. More detail about difference between app-only and delegate you can refer [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/permission_scopes)

Comment: Thanks Fei for your help,  if I parse the token I can see only scp claim not the roles.  "scp": "Calendars.Read User.Read".  How would I get roles instead of scp claims any suggestions?

Comment: You can refer [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only) for the detail step and I would update the orignal post to use the ADAL to request the app-ohly token. And please ensure that the config is correct like the figure in the orignal post.

Answer (score 0):

As per microsoft guy to view another user's calendar using /events endpoint, you need a special permission (something like Calendar.Read.Shared) that we are still in the process of adding,Please have a look at below link..

[Microsoft Graph api 403 access denied when reading other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36729370/microsoft-graph-api-403-access-denied-when-reading-other-users)

This thread was posted on 21 Apr 16 by Venkat Ayyadevara - MSFT, I guess still is in progress.

Comment: If you are trying to read other user's calendars (for free/busy) to schedule meetings, you might want to take a quick look at the find meeting times API:  https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_findmeetingtimes